# Boost 1.67 static library with cmake and travis

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, travis-ci

H-e-l-l-o everyone.
I try to build my c++-project with cmake and boost 1.67 in travis-ci.
Below are the source files.

On my linux-computer are installed cmake 3.13.4 from sources and a boost-1.67 from the sources, all the libraries (statically and dynamic) are in the directory "/usr/local/lib/" and all works fine. But in travis-ci I every time see this message:

```
Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
  Boost version: 1.67.0
  Boost include path: /usr/include
  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:
          boost_program_options
  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
```

yml file:

```
language: cpp
dist: xenial
sudo: false
os: linux


matrix:
  include:
    - env: COMPILER=g++-8 BUILD=Debug STANDARD=14
      compiler: gcc
      addons:
        apt:
          update: true
          sources:
            - sourceline: 'ppa:mhier/libboost-latest'
            - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
          packages:
            - g++-8
            - boost1.67
    - env: COMPILER=g++-8 BUILD=Release STANDARD=14
      compiler: gcc
      addons:
        apt:
          update: true
          sources:
            - sourceline: 'ppa:mhier/libboost-latest'
            - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
          packages:
            - g++-8
            - boost1.67

before_script:
  - wget https://cmake.org/files/v3.13/cmake-3.13.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
  - sudo sh cmake-3.13.4-Linux-x86_64.sh -- --skip-license --prefix=/usr

script:
  - cmake .
  - cmake --build .
  - cmake --build . --target package
```

cmake :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)  
project(hcch VERSION 0.1.${VERSION_BUILD})

set(BOOST_ROOT /usr/include/boost/)

# For my linux
#set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR /usr/local/lib)

# For travis-ci host
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
include_directories (${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories (${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

find_package(Boost 1.67 COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED)
find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)

configure_file (
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/version.h.in"
        "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/version.h"
)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(hcch hcch.cpp SourcesCreator.cpp SourcesCreator.h)

set_target_properties(hcch PROPERTIES
        CXX_STANDARD 14
        CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
        COMPILE_OPTIONS -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra
        )

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( hcch ${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR}/libboost_program_options.a )
```

Maybe static libraries are not installed from the ppa:mhier/libboost-latest?
Tell me how to fix it if someone came across.

This is my project https://github.com/angelskieglazki/hcch
regards, max

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the libboost builds from ppa:mhier/libboost-latest do not currently build static libraries, only shared.

If it's essential that you must use a Boost version later than what is provided by libboost-all-dev then you will need to compile boost from source, although you will run the risk of timing out. Instructions for this can be found in [Boost's best practice handbook](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/wiki/BestPracticeHandbook#a12.CONVENIENCE:ConsiderhavingTravissendyourunittestcodecoverageresultstoCoveralls.io).